# integration between Skype For Business Online and Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, skype, skype-for-business-online

I've been searching and searching for ages now, on how to integrate Skype For Business online with an on-premises Exchange 2010.
More specifically I want to be able to see free/busy (availability) in Outlook, based on the status of their SFB status.
The setup is quite simple:
All mailboxes are on the on-premises Exchange 2010 - no hybrid setup nothing is being synched to O365.
The Skype For Business is purely online.

I've found plenty of articles stating that it's supported and some who've reported that they've configured it, but absolutely nothing on how to actually do it.
Does anyone know how to actually do this? Because MS doesn't seem to know either.

Comment: It is more like MS does not care - Exchange 2010 is ridiculously outdated. in fact, mainstream support ended January 2015.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. Free/Busy is an Exchange calendar thing, Status is a Skype availability thing. These two things aren't the same. Are you saying that you want to see their Skype availability status in Outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the SfB client installed as well as Office installed from your O365 subscription then you don't need to "do" anything to make this work. We have the exact scenario as you. If you're running Outlook and Skype then you'll see user's Skype status in Outlook. Note that Skype Status (Available, In A Meeting) isn't the same thing as Exchange Free/Busy information in the Outlook calendar.

Skype running:

[image]

Skype not running:

[image]

Comment: "Note that Skype Status (Available, In A Meeting) isn't the same thing as Exchange Free/Busy information in the Outlook calendar." - while true, the skype client does integrate with the Exchange credentials and calendar to show Exchange info in the Skype client.  :) - which you know...but elaborating for the OP.

Comment: True, although you can't see a Skype contacts' Exchange calendar info in the SfB client... at least not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the elaboration, will mark it as answer and roll out this version of Outlook instead then :)